Appium action chain fails to click button
So I was trying to using appium to click something and move somewhere else to do another click. This is my code.
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.w3c_actions = ActionBuilder(driver, mouse=PointerInput(interaction.POINTER_TOUCH, "touch"))
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(170, 477)
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pointer_down()
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pause(0.1)
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.release()
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pause(0.1)
    #actions.perform()
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.move_to_location(339, 68)
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pointer_down()
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.pause(0.1)
    actions.w3c_actions.pointer_action.release()
    actions.perform()

It doesn't do what I want. Instead, if I uncomment the actions.perform(), it does what I want, but it will cause some delay, as it does two different operations.

You might want to try using click_and_hold instead of pointer_down, or maybe using pointer_up rather than release() might work better for you
